# Cell takes index of its previous cell - Collectionview inside Tableview

Tags: iphone, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to dynamically add collection view inside tableview. I have make following code.

A cell class for collectionview

```
class NewsFeedCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewSlider: UIImageView!
}
```

Than assign collectionview in Tableview cellforrow at indexpath

```
cell.collectionViewNewsFeed.tag = indexPath.row
cell.collectionViewNewsFeed.reloadData()
```

Than added following delegates of collectionview

```
// MARK: - Collection view Delegates / Datasources

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (mutableArrayNewsFeed[collectionView.tag]["images"] as! NSArray).count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("NewsFeedCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsFeedCollectionViewCell
    print("tag : \(collectionView.tag) , Row : \(indexPath.row)")
    let img = (mutableArrayNewsFeed[collectionView.tag]["images"] as! NSArray)[indexPath.row] as? String ?? "imgLoginScreenLogo"
    cell.imageViewSlider.image = UIImage(named: img)
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Collection View Row : \(indexPath.row)")
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                           sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize{
    return collectionView.frame.size
}
```

Its adjusting properly but the indexes gets changes while i scroll the collectionview. For ex, I scroll collectionview upto 3 cell than i go to the tableview 4th index than it also set the index of 4th index of collectionview to 3rd.

Simply want to add collection view with multiple images inside Table view. I have added, but after scrolling the collection view to 3rd image on 1st cell of tableview, i move to 4th cell of Tableview, there also the collectionview gets scrolled automatically upto 4th cell.

Need to get out of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue with the indexpath, I get the solution by keeping the indexpath in an array.

Refer Following link
https://github.com/ashfurrow/Collection-View-in-a-Table-View-Cell